# New Rails Heroku app throwing an ApplicationError (Heroku error H10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've just deployed a (formerly working) Rails app to Heroku. The issue is that whenever I go to the URL it fails out with an Application Error. I'm honestly not sure what to make of this; most similar errors talk about sqlite3, but that's been removed from the app already. I'm not sure what to make of this beyond that, any suggestions?

```
←[32m2013-03-09T21:57:55+00:00 heroku[run.5406]:←[0m State changed from up to co
mplete
←[35m2013-03-09T21:57:58+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App c
rashed" method=GET path=/ host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="12.13.14.15, 99.249.8
.176" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[35m2013-03-09T21:57:58+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App c
rashed" method=GET path=/ host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="12.13.14.15, 99.249.8
.176" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[35m2013-03-09T21:57:58+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App c
rashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="12.13.14.1
5, 99.249.8.176" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[35m2013-03-09T21:57:59+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App c
rashed" method=GET path=/ host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="12.13.14.15, 99.249.8
.176" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to
starting
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command
`bundle exec rails server -p 22371`
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:27+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rai
ls 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be remove
d in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in t
o your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the releas
e notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2
-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:
5)
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:27+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rai
ls 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be remove
d in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in t
o your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the releas
e notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2
-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:
5)
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Rails 3.2.11 application start
ing in production on http://0.0.0.0:22371
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Call with -d to detach
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Booting WEBrick
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Connecting to database specified
by DATABASE_URL
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gem
s/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /app
/app/models/message.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC (SyntaxError)
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   validates :content, :length =>
{ maximum: => 200 }
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
             ^
2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app
←[36m[web.1]:←[0m       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.
2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dep
endency'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_o
n'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_
or_load'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_lo
ad!'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <modul
e:Finisher>'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializ
ers'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir
e'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_
dependency'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'

←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config.ru:in `new'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from script/rails:6:in `require'

←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to
 crashed
←[35m2013-03-09T21:58:32+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App c
rashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="12.13.14.1
5, 99.249.8.176" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your `Message` model.

```
validates :content, :length => { maximum: => 200 }
```

needs to be

```
validates :content, :length => { :maximum => 200 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error in your message model according to this line in your error message.  Heroku is most likely trying to build your app and when it hits this error it crashes.

```
/app/models/message.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC (SyntaxError)
←[36m2013-03-09T21:58:29+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   validates :content, :length =>
{ maximum: => 200 }
```